# Python code IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a code which lets my microscope to scan the sample:

```
pos = microscope.position
print("Current position: " + json.dumps(pos))
print("Homing")
pos['x'] = 0
pos['y'] = 0
pos['z'] = 0

# units in microns
xyStep = 10
xRange = 400
yRange = 400
zRange = 400
#zBase = maxPosition - micronToStep(zRange/2)
#zBase = -((30000 - 15000)/2)
zBase = -1000

saveData = {
    "xyStep": xyStep,
    "xRange": xRange,
    "yRange": yRange,
    "zRange": zRange,
    "zBase": zBase,
    "data": [[0] * ceil(xRange/xyStep) for i in range(ceil(yRange/xyStep))],
}

measurements = 1
pos = microscope.position
print("Current position: " + json.dumps(pos))

starting_pos = microscope.position
#figure(figsize=(20,5))

ix = 0
iy = 0

totalElapsed = 0
stepsTaken = 1
maxSteps = (xRange/xyStep) * (yRange/xyStep)
up = True

ix = 0
for x in range(-micronToStep(xRange/2), micronToStep(xRange/2) - micronToStep(xyStep), micronToStep(xyStep)):
    iy = 0
    for y in range(-micronToStep(yRange/2), micronToStep(yRange/2) - micronToStep(xyStep), micronToStep(xyStep)):
        start = timer()
        values = []
        if (up):
            pos = {}
            pos['x'] = x + 7500 # declination
            pos['y'] = y - 5500 # declination
            pos['z'] = zBase - micronToStep(zRange/2)
            pos['z2'] = zBase + micronToStep(zRange/2)
            print("Scanning up to position:", pos)

            values = microscope.measureZ(microscope, pos)
            values = np.asarray(values)
            thisTime =  timer() - start
            totalElapsed += thisTime
            up = False
        else:
            pos = {}
            pos['x'] = x + 7500 # declination
            pos['y'] = y - 5500 # declination
            pos['z'] = zBase + micronToStep(zRange/2)
            pos['z2'] = zBase - micronToStep(zRange/2)
            print("Scanning to position:", pos)

            values = microscope.measureZ(microscope, pos)
            values = np.asarray(values)
            values = np.flip(values)
            thisTime =  timer() - start
            totalElapsed += thisTime
            up = True


        print(pos)
        saveData['data'][ix][iy] = values

        iy += 1
        timeLeft = (maxSteps - stepsTaken) * (totalElapsed / stepsTaken) / 60 / 60
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>> Estimated time left: [" + str(timeLeft) + "hr], Per Scan: [" + str(totalElapsed / stepsTaken) + "s][" + str(thisTime) + "], Total Elapsed: [" + str(totalElapsed) + "s], Scans taken: [" + str(stepsTaken) + "] out of: [" + str(maxSteps) + "]")
        stepsTaken += 1
        pickle.dump(saveData, open('saveData.bin', 'wb'))

    ix += 1



pickle.dump(saveData, open('saveData.bin', 'wb'))
```

It works for xyStep = 10, but when I change this parameter to xyStep = 1, after printing Scans taken: [200], I get an error: `in line 149, saveData['data'][ix][iy] = values: IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. The function micronToStep is simply defined: def micronToStep(v): return round((v * 1000)/62).

I assume the problem is with the array dimensions. To be more precise, I can add more information about the code if it is needed to solve this problem.

How to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

`saveData["data"]` is a 400 x 400 list-of-lists.

You have these loops:

```
for x in range(-micronToStep(xRange/2), micronToStep(xRange/2) - micronToStep(xyStep), micronToStep(xyStep)):
    for y in range(-micronToStep(yRange/2), micronToStep(yRange/2) - micronToStep(xyStep), micronToStep(xyStep)):
```

After performing the calculations, the actual range conditions on these loops are:

```
range(-3225, 3209, 16)
```

... which produces slightly more than 400 iterations (402 I believe).  So ix and iy eventually grow too large and produce the out of range error.

Comment: @MalumPhobos Because with xyStep=10, the loops are `range(-3225, 3064, 161)`, which is 39 iterations.  The range step value of 16 vs 161 allows for just a few more iterations of the loop, causing the error.

Comment: I understand. Have you got an idea how to correct this?

Comment: @MalumPhobos You could put something like `if ix >= 400: break` at the top of the outer loop, and `if iy >= 400: break` at the top of the inner loop, as safeguards.

Comment: Or change the loop to be `for ix in range(xRange / xyStep)` to guarantee exactly 400 (or 40) iterations, and then have a separate calculation for the declination value for x inside the loop.

Comment: @ John Gordon Is it possible to modify this condition to make it work with `xyStep < 1` e. x. 0.5?

Comment: @MalumPhobos You can't do that with `range()` because it requires integers, but you could use some other kind of for loop.

Comment: Can you give ma an example of correct loop?

Comment: No I can't, because I don't know exactly what you are _trying_ to do...

Comment: I've added the correct case and explanation in answer.

Comment: I still can't provide an answer.  One possible solution would be to make `saveData["data"]` bigger, i.e. make it 405x405 instead of 400x400, so that it won't be out of range.  But I don't know if this is an _appropriate_ solution for your specific needs.

Comment: I can't help you any more.  Good luck.

Comment: Anyone can explain me how to make `saveData["data"]` bigger, i.e. make it 405x405 instead of 400x400?

Answer (score 0):

The code in post which starts after: "I have a code:" Works correct in case of

```
xyStep = 10
xRange = 400
yRange = 400
```

and prints:

```
Current position: {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0}
Homing
Current position: {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0}
Scanning up to position: {'x': -3226, 'y': -3226, 'z': -3226, 'z2': 3226}
{'x': -3226, 'y': -3226, 'z': -3226, 'z2': 3226}
>>>>>>>>>>>> Estimated time left: [3.450211587398544hr], Per Scan: [7.767830966000474s][7.767830966000474], Total Elapsed: [7.767830966000474s], Scans taken: [1] out of: [1600.0]
Scanning to position: {'x': -3226, 'y': -3065, 'z': 3226, 'z2': -3226}
{'x': -3226, 'y': -3065, 'z': 3226, 'z2': -3226}
>>>>>>>>>>>> Estimated time left: [3.308844005120933hr], Per Scan: [7.454216782500225s][7.140602598999976], Total Elapsed: [14.90843356500045s], Scans taken: [2] out of: [1600.0]
Scanning up to position: {'x': -3226, 'y': -2904, 'z': -3226, 'z2': 3226}
```

and so on. But it stop working for xyStep = 1 and lower this is xyStep = 0.9, xyStep = 0.8... and so on.

The reason is as you write slightly more than 400 iterations in case of xyStep = 1. How to correct the condition to make the program work as in case of

```
xyStep = 0.5
xRange = 400
yRange = 400
```

?